# Convert Comma separated string to XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to convert the string to XML.
I have a string like below. It contains the Programming language names.

```
string lang = "java,php,c#,asp.net,spring,hibernate";
```

I want to convert this string to XML formal like below:

```
<Languages>
  <lang Name="java"/>
  <lang Name="php"/>
  <lang Name="c#"/>
  <lang Name="asp.net"/>
  <lang Name="spring"/>
  <lang Name="hibernate"/>
</Languages>
```

I want to store this XML data in a variable to store later in a database.

Comment: Please, show the code you've tried.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can also be done using Linq-to-XML:

```
using System.Xml.Linq; // required namespace 

XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
XElement xElm = new XElement("Languages",
                    from l in lang.Split(',')
                    select new XElement("lang", new XAttribute("Name", l)                
                    )
                );
xmlDoc.Add(xElm);
```

Comment: I like this solution.  Somehow forgot about Linq-to-XML.

Comment: Well, it's probably the neater way to produce XML in C#

Comment: I do agree, aside from using models and the xml serializer.

Answer (score 2):

A short version of what you have done, using Linq and the string manipulation functions

```
var vales = lang.Split(','); //Splits the CSV
var xmlBody = vales.Select(v => string.Format("<lang Name=\"{0}\"/>",v));
var xml = string.Join(string.Empty, xmlBody); //Potentially add a new line as a seperator
xml = string.Format("<Languages>{0}</Languages>", xml);
```

The other option is to convert your csv into a model that implements ISerialize and then use the xml serializer.  That is more code and not necessarily bad.  If you would like to see an example, feel free to ask and I will post an example.

Answer (score 2):

```
string lang = "java,php,c#,asp.net,spring,hibernate";
string[] langs = lang.Split(',');

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = document.CreateElement("Languages");
document.AppendChild(root);

for (int i = 0; i < langs.Length; i++)
{
    XmlElement langElement = document.CreateElement("lang");
    XmlAttribute nameAttr = document.CreateAttribute("Name");
    nameAttr.Value = langs[i];
    langElement.Attributes.Append(nameAttr);
    root.AppendChild(langElement);
}

document.WriteTo(new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out) {
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working,

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string lang = "java,php,c#,asp.net,spring,hibernate";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat("<Languages>");
            foreach (string s in lang.Split(','))
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("<lang Name=\"{0}\"/>", s);
            }
            sb.AppendFormat("</Languages>");
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. It works just fine.

Comment: I'm quite sure that it is downvoted because constructing XML with string concatenation is very bad practice.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this solution. It solves the problem just like all other answers here. A xml is just text so if someone is capable of doing it manually there is nothing wrong in it. Perhaps more error prone and dangours but doable.

Comment: @t3chb0t I agree with you cause I just follow KISS(Keep it simple stupid), It's gives output like others.